# Specifying wildcard instead of hostname for Wildcard SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl

In wildcard ssl certificates, we will have CN as *.mydomain.com
So it can be replaced with 
host1.mydomain.com,
host2.mydomain.com..etc

My question is :
If we specify
*.mydomain.com(hostname is given as wildcard *)
What does it mean. Is it valid?

Comment: You mean you want to have a wildcard certificate for `*.example.com` in the hope that this will result in a CN of `*.*.example.com`? No, its not valid and even if a CA would issue a certificate like this the browsers would not accept it: see http://serverfault.com/questions/104160/wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-second-level-subdomain

Comment: let me clarify once .. the certificate contains a wildcard entry as *.mydomain.com.
When specifying via browser instead of hostname.mydomain.com I use *.mydomain.com.. Is this valid

Comment: What I wanted to ask is if we have a wildcard certificate with a wildcard entry for a hostname. When we acutally specify the hostname can it again be a wildcard?

Comment: '*.example.com' is no valid hostname. If you use it as part of the URL  the browser will not accept it or at least can not get an IP address for it which also results in failure.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.